# JavaFX Scenebuilder: TextArea and TextField change font

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

for Labels I can change the font easily, but there is not option for TextFields and TextAreas. Is this normal?

Can't I change the font in the scene builder for these object types?

[image: TextArea]

[image: TextField]

[image: Label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the font for a `TextArea` or a `TextField` from Scene Builder; it's done the same way as for a `Label`. Here's a screenshot for `TextArea`:

[image]

Make sure you are using the latest version of Scene Builder. Downloads can be found [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). Note that Scene Builder is maintained by Gluon (for a while now), not Oracle.

Comment: I had the Oracle version installed, after installing the Gluon it works. Thanks